# I need some functions call when app reopen

Tags: flutter

hai I need to call some function when app will reopen from sleep

after user can put app in minimize then when the reopen the app that function have to call in flutter

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen to lifecycle events like this

```
class LifecycleEventHandler extends WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final AsyncCallback resumeCallBack;
  final AsyncCallback suspendingCallBack;

  LifecycleEventHandler({
    this.resumeCallBack,
    this.suspendingCallBack,
  });

  @override
  Future<void> didChangeAppLifecycleState(AppLifecycleState state) async {
    switch (state) {
      case AppLifecycleState.resumed:
        if (resumeCallBack != null) {
          await resumeCallBack();
        }
        break;
      case AppLifecycleState.inactive:
      case AppLifecycleState.paused:
      case AppLifecycleState.detached:
        if (suspendingCallBack != null) {
          await suspendingCallBack();
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}



class AppWidgetState extends State<AppWidget> {
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addObserver(
      LifecycleEventHandler(resumeCallBack: () async => setState(() {
        // here the app has resumed
      }))
    );
  }
  ...
}
```